# Insert a Directory.Build target into project dependency pipeline

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget

I have projects spread across two solutions, call them `Mine.sln` and `Theirs.sln` (and they live in separate repositories).  The projects in `Theirs` are all dependencies for `Mine`.  The two solutions are currently built in sequence.  I would like to change this so that the dependencies are built as a part of `Mine`, eliminating the need to work with two solutions (which are also in separate repositories).  The problem is that in `Theirs`, the projects have `HintPath` properties set on nuget package references (which are pre-sdk projects, unfortunately).

To make this a bit more concrete:

```
Mine.sln (14 projects)
 +=> MP0
 +=> MP1
 +=> ...
 +=> MP13
```

```
Theirs.sln (21 projects)
 +=> TP0
 +=> TP1
 +=> ...
 +=> TP20
```

I have added about 10 or so of the projects from `Theirs` to `Mine`, and there are project dependencies like `MP0 => TP1, TP2`, etc.

The problem: when  `Theirs` are built as dependencies from `Mine`, those `HintPath` properties, which are relative to the `Theirs` solution, are no longer correct and the dependency projects fail to build.   There is a GitHub issue dealing with this problem, although there isn't really a solution: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/738

Modifying projects in `Theirs` isn't really an option, so I was exploring the possibility of doing something like rewriting those properties in memory during the build process.  There is a project to do this on a project-by-project basis, and I've looked at the targets file they use (https://github.com/jstangroome/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite/blob/master/content/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite.targets), but it's per-project and would require modifying projects in `Theirs`, which again, isn't really an option.

My hope was to use `Directory.Build.targets` at the root of `Mine.sln` to set up a target that would run before `ResolveAssemblyReferences` for every project built by this solution.  My `Directory.Build.targets` file looks like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="ReferenceHintPathUpdate" BeforeTargets="BeforeResolveAssemblyReference">
        <Message Text="ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building $(MSBuildProjectName) in $(SolutionDir)" Importance="High" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I only have a `Message` task here to test out build order and dependencies.  I was expecting to see every project name output in the terminal, but I only get output from *some* projects (some referenced by `Mine`, and a few referenced by `Theirs`, but nothing like all of them).  I haven't yet been able to determine why this target only runs for some projects; there doesn't seem to be an obvious common pattern.

Example (filtered) output:

```
ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building MP0 in C:\Users\Me\MySolution
ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building MP1 in C:\Users\Me\MySolution
...
ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building MP7 in C:\Users\Me\MySolution
ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building TP0 in C:\Users\Me\MySolution
ReferenceHintPathUpdate: Building TP4 in C:\Users\Me\MySolution
```

What do I need to do to make a target defined in `Directory.Build.targets` run for every single project built by this solution, *especially* the dependency projects from `Theirs.sln`?

Comment: In case you're not already aware, you can get a binlog by passing `-bl` or `-bl:filename.binlog` to any MSBuild command, and then open it with https://msbuildlog.com. It takes time to learn how to read it, but it's best msbuild debugging there is.  Anyway, if Directory.Build.props isn't being imported, this means that a different Directory.Build.props was found, or the project doesn't import Microsoft.Common.props. Either way something in that repo needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate the projects (or as many as possible) away from using `packages.config` and to using `PackageReference`. `PackageReference` can be used in both legacy style projects and SDK style projects. If you have any .Net Framework ASP.NET projects, those projects can't be migrated and need to continue to use `packages.config`.

With `PackageReference` there is no hint path.

How are you solving the issue of the two repos? Is the version control system git and is `Theirs` pulled in as a submodule in a subdirectory?

I'll assume you can't map or move the `TP*` project directories so that the relative `HintPath` works. (There are some version control systems that support 'overlaying' repos but git submodules don't work that way.)

I'll assume there are projects that can't be changed to `PackageReference` either because the project is .Net Framework ASP.NET or because is it `Theirs`.

For both legacy style and SDK style projects the `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets` files are automatically imported if found. MSBuild searches up the parent directories to find the files. See [Customize the build by folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) and note the section on [Search scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#search-scope).

I find it extremely useful to 'chain' the `Directory.Build.*` files but that has to be explicitly added to each file. See the section on [multi-level merging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#use-case-multi-level-merging).

If the `Theirs` repo is using `Directory.Build.targets` files without chaining, your `Directory.Build.targets` file will not be imported. I expect this is the issue when different projects seem to have different behavior.

The following can be added to all `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets` files.

```xml
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" Condition="'$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))' != ''" />
```

This is a variant of the example `Import` in [multi-level merging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#use-case-multi-level-merging).

Instead of hard-coding the file name, the `$(MSBuildThisFile)` property is used.

If a file is not found, `GetPathOfFileAbove` returns an empty string. It is important to have the `Condition` because `Import` will cause an error when the `Project` attribute evaluates to an empty string. With the `Condition` you don't need to be concerned about which file is highest in the directory structure. It also means the chain is extensible at the top.

I like to consistently have this `Import` at the beginning of a `Directory.Build.*` file. If the `Import` is in different places in different files, the chaining is hard to understand and troubleshoot. Also putting the import at the beginning of a file means the current file can use and/or override things from the imported file.

It would probably be best if you can make the case for a few changes in `Theirs`: use `PackageReference` and add chaining for `Directory.Build.*` files.

Comment: Thanks; this is helpful.  It is indeed the issue that `Theirs` has its own `Directory.Build.targets`, which explains why the projects from `Theirs` are excluded.